# Can VLC deinterlace 405-line video from a DVD?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have some DVDs containing television programmes originally broadcast using the interlaced [405-line system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/405-line_television_system).  When I watch them with VLC, there are clear interlacing artefacts even with interlacing set to 'On'.  I've tried every deinterlacing mode, but none of them eliminate the effect.  It's quite marked when large objects move across the video field.

I'm assuming that VLC's failure to deinterlace is due to the 405-line nature of the video stream.  Is there any way to configure VLC to deinterlate based on 405 scan lines?

This is on a Windows 8.1 machine at a screen resolution of 3840x2160.

Comment: Do you get a better picture if you use a DVD player and television? It seems as though the artefacts are present in the recording, not in its rendering. It's a long time since I watched a 405-line television, but I do recall that the long remanence of the screens then in use concealed a lot of what we would now see as objectionable artefacts.

Comment: Using a DVD player with a modern television I see no artefacts -- but perhaps the telly is somehow compensating.

Comment: OK, it's a puzzler: could your PC be under-powered and unable to keep up in real time? DVD players do have some quite good rendering software, and I'm surprised that VLC does not have at least as good. Are other players (mplayer, wmplayer, etc) any better? Also, if you have an HDMI lead, does it look any better if you watch the PC output on your TV? I use VLC a lot, though mostly on Linux, and I've never had this sort of problem, though I've not had your type of source material.